# Making a WPF TextBox be only as wide as the room it has but expand when the space expands?

Tags: wpf, xaml, textbox, width

Notice how the textbox expands to the right until it has enough horizontal space to fit the content? Well I'd like it to not expand and fit the text with the space it has in the window.

[image]

If the windows expands, then the Grid.Column it's in will expand, but the textbox itself should expand to fit. Simple enough?

Any suggestions? This is my first foray into WPF and so far it's been pretty sleek.

Edit: Here's my XAML markup:

```
<Window x:Class="GameLenseWpf.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="350" MinHeight="450" MinWidth="350">

    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="0.15*" />
            <RowDefinition />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Image Grid.Row="0" Stretch="Fill" Source="Image/topBarBg.png" />
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="0">
            <TextBlock Text="Platform" 
                       Foreground="White" 
                       FontFamily="Georgia"
                       FontSize="15" 
                       Margin="10"
                       HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                       VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
            <ComboBox x:Name="cmbPlatform" 
                      Margin="10"
                      FontFamily="Georgia"
                      FontSize="15"
                      MinHeight="30"
                      MinWidth="140"
                      VerticalAlignment="Center"
                      VerticalContentAlignment="Center" SelectionChanged="cmbPlatform_SelectionChanged">
                <ComboBoxItem>All Platforms</ComboBoxItem>
                <ComboBoxItem>Playstation 3</ComboBoxItem>
                <ComboBoxItem>XBox 360</ComboBoxItem>
                <ComboBoxItem>Wii</ComboBoxItem>
                <ComboBoxItem>PSP</ComboBoxItem>
                <ComboBoxItem>DS</ComboBoxItem>
            </ComboBox>
        </StackPanel>
        <Image x:Name="imgAbout" Grid.Row="0" Source="Image/about.png" 
               Height="16" HorizontalAlignment="Right"
               VerticalAlignment="Center"
               Margin="0 0 10 0"    />
        <ListBox Grid.Row="1" x:Name="lstGames" Background="#343434" Padding="5">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid Height="120" Margin="0 10">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="90"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                        <Border BorderBrush="#202020" BorderThickness="5" CornerRadius="4" Panel.ZIndex="0">
                            <Image Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Source="{Binding ImageUrl}" Stretch="Fill"/>                            
                        </Border>

                        <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Margin="12 0 0 0">
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <TextBlock Text="Title:" FontFamily="Arial" Foreground="White"/>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" FontFamily="Arial" Foreground="White" />
                            </StackPanel>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <TextBlock Text="Release Date:" FontFamily="Arial" Foreground="White" />
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding ReleaseDate}" FontFamily="Arial" Foreground="White" />
                            </StackPanel>
                            <TextBlock Text="Synopsis" FontFamily="Arial" Foreground="White" />
                            <TextBox Background="#454545" Text="{Binding Synopsis}" MinHeight="76" />
                        </StackPanel>  
                    </Grid>                    
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>            
        </ListBox>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: It's impossible to answer without seeing your XAML... By default the TextBox takes all the available space, but no more (HorizontalAlignment=Stretch). How did you define the ItemTemplate and ItemContainerStyle in your ListBox ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To get a TextBox to wrap inside a ListBox you can make the following changes:

1. Set the content of the listbox equal to the width of the listbox using: HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch".
2. Disable the horizontal scrollbar of the listbox to prevent listbox from getting the desired size of the controls and preventing the word wrap in your textbox.
3. Set TextWrapping="Wrap" in the TextBox

Here is the XAML:

```
<ListBox Grid.Row="1" x:Name="lstGames" Background="#343434" Padding="5" 
         ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
         HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" >
</ListBox>

<TextBox Text="{Binding Synopsis}" MinHeight="76" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
```

Comment: Thanks! Setting the ContentAlignment of the ListBox did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need to set the Margin property of your textbox control. In the designer, you can see little circles around each textbox (and each control when you focus them, for that matter). Click the little circle on the right side of the textbox, to make that control grow marginally with the available space in the current layout control (by clicking the circle, the margin will be added into the XAML).

I don't know if in your image you've already adjusted the window size, but with that image it appears you'll also need to set the width for your textbox.

Does this help?

Comment: No, setting the margin (right) property to something didn't help. It still expands to the right.

Comment: Ok, sorry I misread your initial post. You need to set the TextWrapping property for the textbox.

Comment: Sergio, did this solve your issue? I tested it with the Margin set (in my original answer) and with the TextWrapping property set to Wrap. The result was functionality as you described, where the text would wrap to a new line based upon the size of the parent layout control.

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't solve my issue. :( Do you mind posting your xaml so I can diff it with mine and see what I'm doing differently. I too don't understand what setting a margin and text wrap wouldn't solve it, but on my machine it doesn't.

Comment: In other situations, what Fishz described has worked for me (specifically the `TextWrapping="Wrap"` - but I tried it with your exact code and it didn't work as I expected. I'm trying to see what I can see now.